# How to get printed ranges for different pages

Tags: .net, excel

I have a WorkSheet object without print area.
Excel can separate this sheet between pages. It does it when I save this sheet as pdf or print it.

How I can get this areas?
I want something like this:

```
worksheet.PageSetup.Pages[1].Range
worksheet.PageSetup.Pages[2].Range
```